# What relation have the Markov Property with Queueing Theory?

Tags: self-study, stochastic-processes, exponential-distribution

What relation have the Markov Property of Exponential Distribution, with Queueing Theory?
i need to know the utility relation between Markov Property and Queueing Theory

edit: its open to a better and additional answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's related with theory of queues from its definition if we read the Queueing Theory and Markov Property whats about:.

You can think of a queue or a queue node as almost a black box. Jobs or "clients" arrive in the queue, possibly wait some time, take some time to process, and then exit the queue.

[image]

However, the tail node is not a pure black box, as some information about the interior of the tail node is needed. The queue has one or more "servers", each of which can pair with an arriving job until its departure, after which that server is free to pair with another arriving job.

[image]

In this way the markov property is related to the theory of queues, we are talking about a node that passes from one state to another without having memory of the previous events only of the present and the future state.
[image]

$P(X_n+1 | X_n )$

[image]

Markov processes use an exponential variable because no matter how much time has elapsed since the last movement in the distribution, the time until the next movement only depends on the state of the process (and not on the waiting time).

edit: i had to solve this myself after learn various of definitions.
nobody understand my question and downvote... why?.